# Bootstrap grid not wrapping properly?

Tags: html, css, grid

I am practicing this grid system and the grid isn't wrapping properly, it overlaps each other's text as can be seen in the screenshot below:

[image: Error 404]

I am using the version: 3.3.7.

Here's the [code](https://pastebin.com/6LKP0Fvc) that's resulting in this error:

Code:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">           
            <p>ROW 1</p>
        </div>  
        <div class="col-md-4">            
            <p>ROW 1.1</p>
        </div>
```

Error:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">          
            <p>ROW 1</p>
        </div>  
        <div class="col-md-4">            
            <p>ROW 1.1</p>
        </div>  
    </div>
      <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">          
            <p>ROW 2 DASKLLLLDASSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS</p>
        </div>  
        <div class="col-md-3">            
            <p>ROW 2.1 DASKLLLLDASSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS</p>
        </div>  
        <div class="col-md-3">          
            <p>ROW 2.2 DASKLLLLDASSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS</p>
        </div>  
        <div class="col-md-3">            
            <p>ROW 2.3 DASKLLLLDASSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS</p>
        </div>  
    </div>  
  </div>
```

Any help as to why it won't wrap the text properly would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is happening because the content inside the containers is one word that is too long for the column. If you simply must have that long of a word in each container you can try applying word wrap to your paragraph tags as follows:

```
<style>
    p {
        word-wrap:break-word;
    }
</style>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, I figured that out. Just in the video he could do it without the word-wrap so I didn't know if something changed or not. Thanks you too though!